# Regular Expression seperate groups before a line of special characters

Tags: ios, regex

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
This PM was sent by [ helloworld ] hellworld@gmail.com,
Membership Status : YES
http://gg.com.zz/US?id=gg@1

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
Title           : Testing is testing
Quantity        : 44
Price           : 55.00
Item Location   : United States

*******************************************************************


I want this message right here, hello there, you help is deeply 
**
appreciated :)

  *** This email was sent using gg.gg.com ***
```

Above would be my output string, I wish to get groups between the long `^^^^^^-` and `******` divider,

End result would be:

```
This PM was sent by [ helloworld ] hellworld@gmail.com,
Membership Status : YES
http://gg.com.zz/US?id=gg@1
```

```
Title           : Testing is testing
Quantity        : 44
Price           : 55.00
Item Location   : United States
```

```
I want this message right here, hello there, you help is deeply 
**^
appreciated :)
```

I had try `(?<=^)[^\^]*|[^\^-]*(?<=\*\*)` but just couldn't match the whole long `^^^^^^^` divider, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: [`\^+-\s*((?:(?!\^+-|\*+)[\s\S])*)|\*+\s*([\s\S]+?)(?=\s+\*+\s*This email was sent)`](https://regex101.com/r/PwoJqY/1)

Comment: For such an "easy" task, why do you use a regular expression instead of scanning the text manually for your patterns inside a loop? This would be easier to read, easier to be maintained/debug, and (as a bonus) way more performant. Just scan the text line-per-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture your intended data,

```
(?s)^(?:\^+-|\*{3,})\s*(.+?)(?=\s*(?:\^+|\*{3,}))
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` - Enables `.` to match newline character which is required here as the data to be captured spans across multiple lines
- `^` - Matches start of text
- `(?:\^+-|\*{3,})\s*` - Matches one or more `^` characters ending with `-` or three (why three so the last line doesn't match as it has 2 stars) or more `*` characters followed by optional whitespace
- `(.+?)` - Matches the intended text and captures it in first grouping pattern
- `(?=\s*(?:\^+|\*{3,}))` - Look ahead to ensure it stops capturing the data followed by optional whitespace and above pattern like `^^^^^-` or `*****`

Although my previous answer also worked, but this is even better as it neatly captures data.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gMuNym/1)**